# magento2.2 layered navigation limit items

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, css, layered-navigation

i'm wondering is it possible to limit filter section in layered navigation somehow? i have one category with large amount of values (~100), i'd like to limit it somehow, for example by scrollbar etc.

i have found one suggestion to add css style:

```
dl#narrow-by-list dd >ol {
max-height: 150px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but it doesnt work for me. probably my layered navi using another style?

Comment: large amount of values means attributes or price?

Comment: attribute values, like sizes